Is there a way to forecast by subgroup without forecasting each subgroup separately?
I am trying to find an appropriate model to forecast the number of applications received at the end of a recruitment cycle based on previous recruitment cycles and the number of applications received this cycle so far - it would be very helpful to be able to break down this final forecast into different subgroups (e.g. we expect 1,000 applications and of these, we expect 200 to be for this position and of these, we expect 50 to come from this part of the country, and of these, we expect 1 to have a PhD).
We have very good data on the subgroups in our current data, but some of the subgroups are very small (many with fewer than 10 applicants) so I'm not sure if it would be robust to forecast them separately (which is how I believe most autoregressive models would need to do it).
Is there a way to do this which is robust and produces accurate forecasts?

You can forecast the total and the proportions within that as a top-down model, as an alternative to forecasting the individual groups and so their sum as a bottom-up model.

@Henry: that is one possibility. However, this will only work for one hierarchy (e.g., disaggregation by position or by region or by education). (Unless you want to do the full granularity, down to single position $\times$ single region $\times$ single education level.) One of the advantages of the hierarchical approach I am recommending is that it does not have any issues about this. Another one is that it leverages forecasts on all intermediate levels of the hierarchy.

If you can cut your data into MECE (mutually exclusive and collectively exhaustive) subsets, you can use the by now well-established machinery of hierarchical forecasting, which in my experience improves accuracy on all levels of the hierarchy.
What is important - but often not explicitly discussed in the hierarchical forecasting literature - is that you can trivially model multiple hierarchies, so your Grand Total could be subdivided into:

Geography: international vs. national applicants, with international ones subdivided by country or continent or country within continent, and national ones by region or state or region within state
Education: highest diploma Ph.D. vs. master (M.Sc. vs. others) vs. bachelor (B.Sc. vs. others)
Position applied for, again subdivided as useful
Seniority
etc.

Essentially, you categorize the historical data, then forecast each node of the hierarchy separately. These forecasts will not be sum consistent, so the second step is to post-process them. There have been a couple of different proposals on how exactly to do the last step. Since you have some small cell counts, it may be important to pick a method that ensures that the modified forecasts are nonnegative. When I did that a couple of years back, I just used a constrained optimizer.
The important part is that this framework is completely agnostic as to where the original forecasts came from. They can be ARIMA, judgmental, or whatever.
Here is more information on hierarchical forecasting: https://otexts.com/fpp3/hierarchical.html
Of course, low counts will always be a challenge, at least in relative terms, because signals of predictors will usually be weaker than for high counts. But that is just the way things are, no way around this.

That's really interesting, thank you very much for the suggestion!
